# dynamic sql - assigning variable a value from result of dynamic sql query

Tags: sql-server

Been struggling with this one for a good while now.  I'm trying to use `sp_executesql` below:

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);   
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);  
DECLARE @IntVariable int;  
DECLARE @fulldbtablename nvarchar(500);  
DECLARE @ID bigint;  

SET @fulldbtablename = QUOTENAME(@databasename) + '.[DBO].' + QUOTENAME(@tablename)

SET @SQLString = N'SELECT TOP 1 @IDOut = ID FROM' + @fulldbtablename + 'WHERE LastModified < DATEADD(DAY, @daystokeep, GETDATE()) order by 1 desc';  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@daystokeep int,  
@IDOut bigint OUTPUT';  
SET @IntVariable = -1; 

EXECUTE sp_executesql  
@SQLString  
,@ParmDefinition  
,@daystokeep = @IntVariable 
,@IDOut = @ID OUTPUT;
```

I'm getting the error `Must declare the scalar variable "@ID"`

I've reviewed the help below, but I can't shake this error.  Has anyone any ideas?  I am declaring @ID in `DECLARE @ID bigint;`

To help me debug, I split the query into a new window and ran the query below which completes successfully so I am pulling my hair out:

```
DECLARE @Databasename varchar(500)
DECLARE @Tablename varchar(500)
DECLARE @ID bigint;
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);  
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);  
DECLARE @IntVariable int;  
DECLARE @fulldbtablename nvarchar(500); 

SET @databasename = 'DatabaseName'
Set @Tablename = 'TableName'
SET @fulldbtablename = QUOTENAME(@databasename) + '.[DBO].' + QUOTENAME(@tablename)

SET @SQLString = N'SELECT TOP 1 @IDOut = ID FROM' + @fulldbtablename + 'WHERE LastModified < DATEADD(DAY, @daystokeep, GETDATE()) order by 1 desc';  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@daystokeep int,  
@IDOut bigint OUTPUT';  
SET @IntVariable = -1; 

EXECUTE sp_executesql  
@SQLString  
,@ParmDefinition  
,@daystokeep = @IntVariable 
,@IDOut = @ID OUTPUT;  

SELECT @ID
```

Anyone any ideas??????  Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at using `sp_executesql` with an `OUTPUT` variable? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

Comment: I did thanks Erik, but I couldn't make it stick with the dynamic table name and the SELECT TOP 1 (ID).  I might just be being thick but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried for that?

Comment: ` DECLARE @sqlcommand nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT TOP 1 (ID) from ' + @tablename + ' where LastModified < DATEADD(DAY,' + @NumberOfKeepDays + ', GETDATE()) order by 1 desc'

execute sp_executesql 
    @sqlcommand,
    N'@ID bigint OUTPUT', 
    @ID = @ID output; `

Comment: Please use `QUOTENAME(@tablename)` at the very least. You could also add checks to make sure `@tablename` exists, [prefix it with the right schema](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix), etc. I wrote a two-part tip on SQL injection [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/) and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/).

Answer (score 2):

You were missing the variable assignment inside the dynamic SQL batch.

```
DECLARE @sqlcommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT TOP 1 @ID = (ID) --Assign me!
                                     FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + ' 
                                     WHERE LastModified < DATEADD(DAY,' + @NumberOfKeepDays + ', GETDATE()) 
                                    ORDER BY 1 DESC';

EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @sqlcommand, N'@ID BIGINT OUTPUT', @ID = @ID OUTPUT;
```

The example from the `sp_executesql` [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) is pretty clear, though suffers from formatting.

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);  
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);  
DECLARE @SalesOrderNumber nvarchar(25);  
DECLARE @IntVariable int;  

SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @SalesOrderOUT = MAX(SalesOrderNumber) --Assign me!
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader  
    WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID';  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@CustomerID int,  
    @SalesOrderOUT nvarchar(25) OUTPUT';  
SET @IntVariable = 22276;  

EXECUTE sp_executesql  
    @SQLString  
    ,@ParmDefinition  
    ,@CustomerID = @IntVariable  
    ,@SalesOrderOUT = @SalesOrderNumber OUTPUT;  
-- This SELECT statement returns the value of the OUTPUT parameter.  
SELECT @SalesOrderNumber;
```

If you want to learn a whole heck of a lot about dynamic SQL, SQL injection (and you should, because what you're executing now is potentially unsafe), head [over here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: I'm getting "Must declare the scalar variable "@ID", despite declaring it earlier in the script.  I think it's to do with 'SELECT TOP 1 @ID = (ID)

Comment: @Stephen sorry to hear that, but without seeing it, I can't help you. I have `@ID` declared for the dynamic SQL in my example.

Comment: Thanks for helping Erik:
`
DECLARE @sqlcommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT TOP 1 @ID = (ID)
                                     FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + ' 
                                     WHERE LastModified < DATEADD(DAY,' + CONVERT(varchar(20), @NumberOfKeepDays) + ', GETDATE()) 
                                    ORDER BY 1 DESC';

EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @sqlcommand, N'@ID BIGINT OUTPUT', @ID = @ID OUTPUT;

SET @ID = CEILING(@ID/1000.0)*1000

Comment: @Stephen you are not declaring `@ID` anywhere in that script. You have to do it both inside and outside of the dynamic SQL batch. If you want to add code, please update your question instead of pasting it in comments. Also, I'd urge you to look at example code from the links I posted.

Comment: sorry I'm not really helping myself.  I've editing the question above which hopefully makes it clearer.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Stephen it looks like you just have ID and IDOut transposed now?

Comment: Sorry Erik, don't understand what you mean..?

Comment: @Stephen that's my fault, I misunderstood your update. So the code runs in one SSMS window but not the original? Or is there another context it doesn't run in?

Comment: Erik, the top code section is run in a stored procedure, triggered by a job. To debug, I stripped out the code into a query window (declaring and setting variables used as parameters in the s/p). The bottom code runs fine in another Ssms window

Comment: @Stephen we gotta start way over here. My answer won't help with that. I'll keep responding, but you gotta ask a brand new question with all the code and details of what's not working. The comment back and forth is difficult at best.